# How to write this nested foreach loop query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can you please help me write this nested foreach loop in LINQ?

```
c=0
foreach(var e in elements)
{  
     foreach(var a in e.Attributes)
     {
          if(a.Name=="City" && a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland")                                                 
                 c += 1;                    
     }
}
```

Comment: Show us your attempt. What is `c` supposed to be for? Just a count?

Comment: `var c = elements.SelectMany(e => e.Attributes).Count(a => a.Name == "City" && a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this (Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Count` methods):

```
int c = elements.SelectMany(e => e.Attributes)
                .Count(a => a.Name == "City" && a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland");
```